# FullCalendar is removing all recurring events instead of event that matches filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to remove one event from a recurring event. I am using the ice_cube gem to assist with recurring events.  All of the functionality works for creating and editing recurring events.

If a user wants to delete one event of a recurring event I use the following:

```
  eventClick: (event, jsEvent, view) ->
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
    return
```

Where event._id is an unique id fullCalendar creates for each event on the calendar.
However, instead of removing the one event of the recurring events that is passes it removes all of the events.

What am I doing wrong and how can I get fullCalendar to remove only one event of a sequence of events?

Answer (score 1):

[FullCalendar event doc page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) says that recurring events have the same ID.

[removeEvents doc page](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEvents) says that you can provide a filtering function if you want to delete a single event object.

```js
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (eventCandidate) {
        return calEvent === eventCandidate;
    });
}
```

**UPD**: if the filtering function doesn't work, [custom rendering hook](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) might help.

You would probably have to set a [custom property](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) on the event (or remember its ID and date somewhere) and then exclude such an event during the render.

```js
eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    calEvent.excludedByUser = true;
},
eventRender: function(calEvent, element) {
    if (calEvent.excludedByUser) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan I tried this using the date of the event clicked. I checked the console for the filter function and I get only one event returning true yet it still deletes all of the events. Also the event._id is unique. FullCalendar supplies this id for each event.

Comment: I just tried this code and it still deletes all of the recurring events. I used calEvent._id == eventCandidate._id.  I get only one true so it finds the correct event but it still deletes all recurring events.

Comment: I  have a custom property called 'deleted: false' that I could set to true on the eventClick event. However, I would need to re-render all of the events in order for the event to be removed from the view. I was hoping there was a way I could avoid the re-rendering to remove the element.

Comment: The other thing is that I can add the deleted:false and hide the event by adding a hidden class to the event, but when I add another event to the calendar, the recurring event I deleted reappears on the calendar for some reason.

Comment: @chell I think the calendar just replaces the event's DOM element so your custom class disappears. Maybe you could combine those two approaches (set custom class and the custo property so that rerender will still hide the deleted event)

Comment: thanks I am doing that actually: eventRender: (event, eventElement) -> if event.deleted
          eventElement.find('div.fc-content').addClass 'deleted'
However, this only works when I re-render all the events.  I need to update the array of events from fullCalendar removing the event that was clicked but that removeEvents method does not seem to work. It still removes all of the elements.

Comment: @chell I guess it's just not possible since your source array just doesn't have an instance for each occurrence of the event.I suppose saving the deletion of the single occurrence requires some custom ID (like <eventID>-<ocurrenceTimestamp>) that would be passed to server for marking as deleted. 
Then you could load the list of excluded IDs and check it in eventRender hook.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. They were helpful and I did give them a try. I am able to create an exclusion and I use a gem called ice_cube to manage all of this and it works quite well.  The source array has an instance of each event but the id is not unique which seems to be the issue. So the way I have it working is I create an exception for the date of the event and then reload all of the events on the calendar. I was just hoping I could find a way to not have to reload them.